# Grunt running mocha - aborts when test fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, gruntjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to learn this automated unit test malarkey. I want to use Grunt to run my Mocha tests automatically, and output test results to a file. As far as I can make out, I need to use the [grunt-mocha-cov](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-mocha-cov) for this. I've sort of got it working: when the tests pass Grunt writes out the results file OK. But when one of them fails I get this:

```
Running "mochacov:all" (mochacov) task
Warning:  Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

And no file is created. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

My project's organised like this:

[image]

My test folder contains a single file, test.js, which looks like this:

```
   var chai = require("chai"),
   assert = chai.assert,
   expect = chai.expect;

    var foobar = {
      sayHello: function() {
        return 'Hello World!';
      }
    }

    describe('Foobar', function() {
      describe('#sayHello()', function() {
        it('should work with assert', function() {
          assert.equal(foobar.sayHello(), 'Hello World!');
        });
        it('should work with expect', function() {
          expect(foobar.sayHello()).to.equal('Hello Worlxd!');
        });
      });
    });
```

package.json has this:

```
{
  "name": "GruntTest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-mocha-cli": "~1.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.4",
    "grunt-mocha": "~0.4.1",
    "should": "~2.0.1",
    "chai": "~1.8.1",
    "grunt-mocha-cov": "0.0.7"
  },
  "description": "Grunt Test",
  "main": "grunt.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD"
}
```

And here's my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    mochacov: {
       options: {
         reporter: 'XUnit',
         require: ['should'],
         output: 'test-results.xml',
         bail: false
       },
       all: ['test/*.js']
     }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-cov');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['mochacov']);

};
```

---

EDIT

Following xavier's advice I got it working with mochacov and the xunit-file reporter. Here's my new improved Gruntfile, in case useful to anyone else:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    mochacov: {
     options: {
       reporter: 'xunit-file',
       require: ['should'],
       bail: false
     },
     all: ['test/*.js']
   }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-cov');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['mochacov']);

};
```

The terminal gives the warning "Aborted due to warnings", but mochacov creates a file xunit.xml with the test results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that one: https://github.com/yaymukund/grunt-simple-mocha

with one of the following reporter: http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#reporters

or something like this: https://github.com/peerigon/xunit-file

but the truth is that you should ditch grunt from the server side, and use a Makefile!

here is a classic one i use:

```
MOCHA="node_modules/.bin/mocha"
_MOCHA="node_modules/.bin/_mocha"
JSHINT="node_modules/.bin/jshint"
ISTANBUL="node_modules/.bin/istanbul"

TESTS=$(shell find test/ -name "*.test.js")

clean:
    rm -rf reports

test:
    $(MOCHA) -R spec $(TESTS)

jshint:
    $(JSHINT) src test

coverage:
    @# check if reports folder exists, if not create it
    @test -d reports || mkdir reports
    $(ISTANBUL) cover --dir ./reports $(_MOCHA) -- -R spec $(TESTS)

.PHONY: clean test jshint coverage
```

that's it, just install mocha, jshint and istanbul as dev dependencies and you're good to go

some people will tell you to install these tools globaly, but it's up to you

Comment: Thanks xavier - grunt-simple-mocha is just outputting to the console, and I'm having trouble getting xunit-file to work. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Last time I used grunt on server side it was like this: https://github.com/xseignard/rss-unify/tree/a560641050a3e8e06bb040220e53feff83a1003d/server take a look